# Android button background shape: circle is squished

Tags: android

fragment_camera.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_camera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_take_pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle" >
    </Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

circle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="#87cefa"/>

    <size
        android:width="40dp"
        android:height="40dp"/>
</shape>
```

Result:

[image]

My circle is squished *cry*.

As the button does not contain any content I'm guessing the button has a default width and height. How can I get the button to adjust itself to the drawable? Must I set the width and height the same dimensions as the drawable, or is there a dynamic way of doing this?

Comment: No, you can't. The only way is to define the dimensions of the button. The background drawable is always forced to the view's dimensions.

Comment: @iRaviiVooda Alright this is what I was afraid of, guess I have to bite the bullet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop crying. Use a **compound drawable**.
It would be `drawableLeft` for occidental people, or `drawableRight` for mid-oriental people (it really depends on how you want your image and text to be related - you can even use both of them).
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html

Comment: Using compound drawables makes it look off-centred and it doesn't look right. Use ImageButton instead as per @KarlMorrison's suggestion or just define button dimensions.

Comment: @zboarda No, it does not. I'm successfully using it in my apps. And the OP wouldn't accept my answer, if it was like you say.

Comment: Hmm, sorry about that. When I previewed it in layout editor, it showed the image offset to the left. Will check for myself again.

Comment: drawableLeft shows a drawable to the leftmost side of the Text. drawableRight shows it to the rightmost side. drawableTop and drawableBottom... you can figure it out. You can set one, none or any combination of these compound drawables, if so you wish. But only the TextView as a whole will be clickable. Therefore, they are of no use for a joystick - unless you handle the onTouch position. But for a "label with icon", they are great. And more performing than an ImageView with a TextView plus a container.

Comment: Moreover, you can add an additional margin between the drawable and the text.

Comment: Using TextView and compound drawable is only if you want to show text and image. The OP asks without text. Therefore, ImageButton is a better way to go. Have tried it in the app and it shows a massive gap with a Button and drawableLeft if there's no text, therefore Button should be avoidable if you're just showing an image.